# Error class Java.util.Vector casting method

Tags: java, vector

I'm using `import java.util.Vector`, and when I get to the line in red where I use the Vector, the below error occurs:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class javax.swing.JTable cannot be cast to class java.util.Vector (javax.swing.JTable is in module java.desktop of loader 'bootstrap'; java.util.Vector is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

My method:

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
     try {
            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream("Dados.bin");
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(file);

            //TODO: ERROR NEXT LINE
            Vector<Vector> tableData = (Vector<Vector>)input.readObject();
            
            input.close();
            file.close();
            
            DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tblClientes.getModel();
            for (int i = 0; i < tableData.size(); i++){
                Vector row = tableData.get(i);
                model.addRow(new Object[]{row.get(0), row.get(1), row.get(2), row.get(3)});
            };
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I tried some alternative codes but without success.

Comment: The error you have encountered is a ClassCastException. Which means you are going to cast a `javax.swing.JTable` object into a `java.util.Vector` object, which is illegal. If you can debug your code, check what is the actual object type of the output of the `input.readObject()` call. Then you can do the casting correctly.

Comment: From your error I would say that the input.readObject() is returning javax.swing.JTable but you are expecting a Vector. My suggestion would be to actually debug the code and see at runtime what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you are not defining the type of the matrix. I suggest declaring the matrix as Vector<Vector>.

`Vector<Vector<Object>> tableData = (Vector<Vector<Object>>)input.readObject();`

Another tip, you can add the matrix without doing a loop, with

`model.setDataVector(tableData, columnIdentifiers);`

columnIdentifiers refer to the name of the columns of the table.
Documentation about this method: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#setDataVector(java.util.Vector,java.util.Vector)